# Stopping https port on wsubdomain

Tags: apache, https, port, centos7

I would like to set a server on port 443 to handle safari web notifications. So I would like to disable port 443 from Apache for that subdomain. I tried doing it by removing the web domain from ssl.conf or setting SSLEngine off after putting the domain on port 80, but in all cases when I execute nmap on the domain port 443 always pops up, and when I execute the other service on port 443 I get an error.
How do I manage it?

Comment: You're not connecting to "a domain" or "a subdomain". Instead, you're resolving a domain name to an IP address and connect to that address (plus a port). Thus, if that IP address & port combo hosts another service that might (or might not) be resolved for any other domain or subdomain, you'll end up with the port being served by another program. Binding the port (httpd's `Listen` directive) is outside of a `VirtualHost` block, that's a hint. Voting to close, as the question is not related to programming (see [help/on-topic] and the [tag:apache] tag description)

Comment: I am sorry if I bothered you, but I supposed this forum was for general computer issues, not just programming. As I said, the 443 port pops up by nmap on websockets.inarrivo.net even if that subdomain is not present in the configuration file. As you may see by connecting to https://websockets.inarrivo.net another domain returns the problem with the certificate, like if it caught up the connection.

Comment: There's no bothering, it's just (neutrally) off topic. Superuser.com is for general computing problems. But I think that my comment already contains all the answer you need...

Comment: It may be so, but I read that each time I open a port on a server, all subdomains open them too. So I wanted to deliver https requests on port 4433 in order to free port 443, but unfortunately the connection to the https service is not established after changing the port.

Comment: No listening socket is opened for a domain. They're on a IP/port, independent of DNS resolution. Everything else is then handled within the application that handles the connection

Comment: Yes, in fact I checked that it is impossible to use different ports in different subdomains, once a port is open on one, it is open everywhere. But this unfortunately takes me to box one, how to have the client connect to the server using another port to submit web notifications.